# Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type while creating array

Tags: c++

I just started with proggraming and i dont know what is happening here.I dont know why my Visual Studio give me error to pointed lines minmax (expression must be a pointer to a complete object type)

```
std::array<float, 2> *minmax(std::vector<float> v) {

int min = v.front();
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    if (min > v.at(i))
        min = v.at(i);
int max = v.front();
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    if (max < v.at(i))
        max = v.at(i);

minmax[0] = min;       <-------
minmax[1] = max;       <-------


}
```

Comment: You are using Pascal syntax to return the value. C++ does it a different way.

Comment: Then what i should change cause i stll dont what to do.

Comment: Instead of just making up stuff, try consulting a language reference manual to see how to return a value from a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to change for this to compile: you haven't defined an array called "minmax", so you need to do that first, before you try to assign the values of min and max to it. Your function also doesn't return the array yet.

Comment: Should i define it in main ?

Comment: The array that your function should return should be defined in the body of the function. This means that something like "std::array<float, 2>* minmax = new std::array<float,2>();" should appear between the two curly braces of the code sample in your question (without the " quotes).

Comment: Except for one more issue (accidentally pressed enter, so separate comment): you have given the array that you are trying to return the same name as your function, so you are probably going to get a warning. It's not a big issue now, but it can be if you ever try to write a recursive function, because it "masks" the name of the function itself within the body of the function, so you wouldn't be able to call the function from the function itself after you have defined this variable. To fix that, simply name the array "result" or something like that instead and then return result.